Spill Array with filter and sum
Thanks in advance!!!
I have a data table (Transaction_Detail) of employee expenses from which I'd like to generate a summary result using the newer array functions.
I'd like to filter the results based upon:
a) date range (cell K$6 and L$6) and;
b) expense type
and produce a two column summary of the Amount column by employee_name.
I've successfully gotten the results anticipated BUT I can only get the results with two separate excel array expressions.  There has GOT to be a way to get this done in ONE expression - but I just cannot make it work!  Help.
Expression 1 (first result array):
=LET(include?,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Transaction_Detail[Account],            (FILTER(I9#,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",H9:H27)))),0))(Transaction_Detail[Date]>=K$6)(Transaction_Detail[Date]<=L$6),names,FILTER(Transaction_Detail[Simpler Name],include?),amounts,FILTER(Transaction_Detail[Amount],include?),HSTACK(names,amounts))

Expresson 2 (produces final result but references the output of Expression 1):
=SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(L45:L2048),SUMIFS(M45:M2048,L45:L2048,UNIQUE(L45:L2048))),2,-1)

